# What tags to use for questions concerning someone's shack

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have [ham-setup](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ham-setup) and [installation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation). Currently the questions are about someone's shack.

Do we want to use a [shack](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shack) tag for these?

There are 582,000 google hits for: "Amateur Radio" shack

There are 6,310 google hits for: "Amateur Radio" "ham setup"

I think we should be focusing on SEO.

Comment: Was already working on a fuller answer dcaswell! And yes: ask ten random people on the street for the meaning of the amateur radio term "shack" and I can almost guarantee that no one would get even close. That, to me, is a jargon test!

Answer (score 3):

I'm kind of in favor of `operating-area` myself, with a *synonym* `shack`. That would be approachable by people who are not familiar with the jargon, as well as provide the (largely) equivalent term for those who *are* familiar with the jargon. The tag wiki could go something like *the shack, or operating area, is the space where... (fill in the blank)*. It also allows for both those who are lucky enough to be able to dedicate a room to their radio operating, as well as those who are stuck at the kitchen table with a handheld radio.

Google for *"Amateur Radio" operating area* returns about 5.6 million hits, whereas *"Amateur Radio" "operating area"* gives me 21,300 hits, including a number of fairly official-looking pages on the first page of hits.

Comment: My only concern with this suggestion is that it could be confused with "the geographic area in which you operate". Maybe [tag:operating-space] instead?

Comment: @dcaswell I'd probably use "shack", but then again I know the jargon. If I was a newcomer, I'd probably start out by searching for something like *amateur radio operating place*, *area*, or a similar term, yes. But then again, English isn't my native language. *My issue is with the term "shack" being jargon;* while it's perfectly usable as a tag synonym (and probably should be, given its prevalence in the community), *I don't think it's the word someone not in the know would use to search!*

Answer (score 1):

[installation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation) seems like it should be avoided in general, since it could refer to either the noun form or the verb form (which have fairly significantly different meanings).

I actually like [ham-setup](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ham-setup) as a more neutral and approachable tag. Yes, [shack](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shack) would be the jargon equivalent, but I think we should try to avoid embedding too much jardon in the tag system itself.

Comment: I don't like "ham-setup".. It just sounds weird.

Comment: @Seth If you can think of a better option, add an answer. The more alternatives available, the better we can make decisions.

Comment: `setup`, IMO, has the same potential dual meaning as `installation` so I'm not sure `ham-setup` would be a good name for a tag. Besides, we're already at **ham**.SE; my feeling is that tags shouldn't need to add redundancy just to be understandable. (Consider: "what other kind of setup is discussed on ham.SE?")

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think the addition here is more to help distinguish between the noun and verb forms (e.g. "ham-installation" would also be clearer that it's the noun form being discussed). That said, I like your suggestion above, with caveats.