# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Amateur Radio SE is going to need a few moderators to help steer the site during the beta phase until the site graduates and an election can be held. We're looking for folks that have a little bit of time to give and are interested in stepping up into leadership roles  within this community.

Good candidates should show a history of:

- Being patient and fair in their dealings with other users
- Being helpful to new users by showing them the ropes
- Expressing interest in the governance and janitorial aspects of this community by participating here on meta

As a pro tempore moderator (or, moderator 'for now') your primary responsibilities will be:

- Helping the community to organize promotional activities to help make others aware of the site - you'll have our ear for any guidance and help you might need
- Handling of flags raised by the community and sometimes settling disputes with diplomacy
- Using your moderator tools to help the community organize and clean up tags, merge duplicate questions to create canonical posts, and other janitorial tasks

The position will take a few hours of your time each week on average, but it's *strictly* volunteer - there's no time clocks to punch. We realize that folks have many obligations.

Please use answers to this post to nominate yourself, or anyone else that you feel would do a good job as a moderator! You don't need a lot of experience with Stack Exchange in general, but you will need enough domain knowledge to be able to judge the quality of posts and whether they fit into the topic scope of the site.

When nominating, link the name to the nominee's profile (both parent and meta). Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

If the nomination was posted by a 3rd-party, the nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer to add that they accept the nomination and optionally write something about themselves.

For more information about the Stack Exchange moderation philosophy and the initial moderator selection process, see here:

- [A theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Moderator pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

I hope to begin contacting interested parties by the end of this week - starting Friday, November 8, 2013. If this sounds like something you'd like to do, please get your hat in the ring!

Answer (score 8):

### [Amber](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/22/amber?tab=summary) ([meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22/amber), [network](http://stackexchange.com/users/49939/amber), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber), nomination accepted)

Amber has been consistently active since the beginning of the beta, active [in multiple areas of the site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/22/amber?tab=badges), has assisted with helping new users[(1)](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/345/why-do-hams-often-conclude-messages-with-73/432#comment393_432)[(2)](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-to-evaluate-antenna-data#comment196_197) and keeping the site on-topic[(1)](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/241/getting-started-with-aprs#comment193_241)[(2)](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/183/what-do-qrm-and-qsb-refer-to/184#comment121_184)[(3)](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/521/installing-cusdr64-on-windows-7-64-bit#comment521_521), is usually available [on chat (133 posts)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/96371/amber), and has been active with [questions (15) and comments (22) on meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22/amber). While not an active moderator, she is consistently active on StackOverflow with [3,000 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber?tab=answers) over [at least four years](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=49) and has been active in [our very own review queues](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/22/amber?tab=activity).

---

Thanks for the nomation, Dan. I'd be willing to step into this role if people are interested in having me do so, but I'd also like to note a couple of things here:

- I am more of a novice ham than expert. I haven't been doing this as a dedicated hobby for years; my knowledge is more general and involves a lot more learning-as-required.
- That said, I do have a large interest in making this site a valuable resource for all kinds of hams, both novice and expert. In fact, I'm very happy with how the site's been developing so far; I think we've managed to strike an excellent balance and I'd like to see that continue.

Regardless of whether I wind up as a moderator, I'll probably continue working the review queues and guiding people who are new to the SE format.

Comment: I don't think guru knowledge is necessary for the job as a moderator, there are much more important traits :)

Comment: As long as you can sufficiently judge the _quality_ of a post, and whether or not it fits the topic, and if it can be reasonably answered in a Q&A setting - you're fine. Remember, we appoint three moderators, so you have the combined domain knowledge of them all (plus the community) when decisions about merges and duplicates have to be made. For the most part, I envision the mods here doing more community building and janitorial (tags, etc) sorts of things, and helping the community reach consensus on meta discussions, of which we're having plenty - which is good!

Comment: @TimPost Yes. I just wanted to make it clear to anyone who was combing through the various people here exactly who they're looking at. :)

Answer (score 6):

### [PearsonArtPhoto](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/13/pearsonartphoto?tab=summary) ([meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/pearsonartphoto), [network](http://stackexchange.com/users/260566/pearsonartphoto?tab=accounts), has accepted nomination)

PearsonArtPhoto has been active consistently since the beginning of the beta, active [in multiple areas of the site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/13/pearsonartphoto?tab=badges) ([including meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/pearsonartphoto) and [more votes than any other user](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters)), is often available [on chat (104 posts in ours, active in other rooms)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3087/pearsonartphoto), and has provided proven quality questions and answers [across 47 different tags](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/13/pearsonartphoto?tab=tags). He has been active in [all of the review queues](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/13/pearsonartphoto?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (with the exception of late answers, because we haven't been around long enough yet). He is a consistently active moderator on at least 3 other sites, including [SciFi/Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98/pearsonartphoto?tab=activity&sort=reviews) and [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/25/pearsonartphoto?tab=activity&sort=reviews). I can't speak as to how much free time that leaves him, but his posts here so far speak for themselves and I don't need to explain why it might be helpful to have someone who's been a moderator elsewhere. And he has the right answer in case you were ever wondering whether [you could have a lunar rover](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/2100).

Answer (score 3):

### [Dan - KD2EE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee?tab=summary) ([meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee), [network](http://stackexchange.com/users/979933/dan?tab=accounts), self-nomination)

I have been active since the beginning of the beta, [in multiple areas of the site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee?tab=badges) ([including meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee) and [voting](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee?tab=summary)), can often be found [in the chat (94 posts)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/97091/dan-kd2ee), and have posted questions and answers [across many different tags](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee?tab=tags). I usually lurk with a window open I am not a moderator on any site, but have been active in the [StackOverflow review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999924/dan?tab=activity&sort=reviews) as well as [our own](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/87/dan-kd2ee?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (including more review activity than any other user).

Answer (score 3):

### [Michael Kjörling](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29/michael-kjorling) ([meta](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/29/michael-kjorling), [network](https://stackexchange.com/users/225818/michael-kjorling), self-nomination)

In the interest of helping out, I'll offer myself as well.

I have been active on the site since very early in the private beta, with (currently) [3 questions and 14 answers (five voted 10 or higher) in 28 tags on the main site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/29/michael-kjorling?tab=tags), and [5 questions and 5 answers in 5 tags on meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29/michael-kjorling?tab=tags). Aside from Ham.SE, I am a long-time member of Stack Overflow (though more as a reader than contributor there currently) and several other sites in the network, and am an active member on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/users/53590/michael-kjorling) (13Q, 122A, 5.2k) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2465/michael-kjorling) (21Q, 109A, 4.9k) where I also on a fairly regular basis check out the review queues. I've had a Stack Exchange user account for a little over three years now and believe I have a good feel for how the network works, and regularly try to guide newcomers in how the Q&A style works and how to write good both questions and answers. Much of my review activity doesn't show up in the review queue stats because I haven't explicitly gone through the review interface; for example, the review interface only shows two close reviews on me, though I have also cast nine close and two reopen votes, which would have put me as #7 on the top close reviewers of all times if those had been counted as well all else being the same. On ham.se, I currently hold the position of [tenth most active voter](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all).

A major consideration for me would be to make the site approachable and welcoming for newcomers (both to the site, the SE network and the amateur radio world), one possible example of which might be [my answer here on meta suggesting the operating-area tag](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/58/29).